# Read data in Plc with Moka7

Tags: java, plc

What parameters do you need these methods?

```
 Client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB,1,1,1,byte[]{2});
 S7.GetDIntAt(byte,1);
```

What values ​​go into the number of each method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AreaType area: one of area type like DB (data block), MK (Merker) and ...

int db: `IF` area type is DB, it will the show db number

int start: show the position of start of bits

int amount: number of bits

DataType type: type of Data like BIT, BYTE, WORD, REAL and ....

byte[] buffer: result will be copy to this array
```

> client.readArea(AreaType.DB, 200, 34, 1, DataType.BYTE, buffer);